# Is the relationship between Customer and Commodity correct?

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship

> It is known about each employee of the shipping company what their
>   first and last names are, their age, residence address, place of
>   birth, correspondence address, e-mail.
>
> Each employee who is a driver has one of the cars at the disposal. It
>   is known about the car what make it is, what engine it has, when it
>   was manufactured, etc.
>
> Each car has a vehicle card, which contains information on failures,
>   services, repairs, etc.
>
> Shipping company has its customers and gathers the following
>   information about them: first and last names, address, telephone no.
>
> Customers commission the company the shipping of commodities. About
>   commodities the following information is known: quantity, weight,
>   address and date of shipping.
>
> Customer can commission the shipping of more than one commodity. It is
>   also known what the price of such a service is.

Please, review this ER Diagram that I have designed.

I have used "Look Across" Min-Max notation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would slightly change the diagram to display the shipping order as an entity (currently in your diagram it's displayed as a relation), with the following :

1. Each customer can have many shipping orders.
2. Each shipping order can contain many commodities.

Hope this helps